# Showing that a 2-cycle and a 5-cycle generate $S_{5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an easy way to do this? I struggle with proving stuff like this about the symmetric group. It seems like this stuff gets hand waved a lot as well. I've been trying to show that this set generates all of the two cycles since that would suffice.

I noticed that this is a specific case of a more general exercise that a $2$ cycle and a $p$ cycle generate $S_{p}$. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose the $2$-cycle is $\tau = (1\ 2)$ and the $5$-cycle is $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$.  How could you get $(1\ 3)$?  *Hint*:  Try conjugating; what is $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$?

Comment: Try proving *this* first: that the $2$-cycles of the form $(i\ i+1)$ generate $S_n$ by showing they generate all the $2$-cycles. Then show that the $2$-cycles of the form $(i\ i+1)$ are conjugates of $(1\ 2)$ by $(1\ 2\  \dots  n)$ or conjugates of conjugates...you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tau = (s_{1} s_{2})$ and $\sigma = (s_{1} s_{2} s_{3} s_{4} s_{5})$. Note that we can always set up $\tau$ and $\sigma$ to $\sigma$ have its first two elements be the elements of $\tau$. Observe that $\sigma \tau \sigma ^{-1}=(s_{2} s_{3})$. Similarly by conjugating $(s_{2} s_{3})$ by $\sigma$ yields $(s_{3} s_{4})$ and we can get $(s_{4} s_{5})$ similarly. In particular we have all of the transpositions of the form $(k~k+1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Observe that $(k+1 ~k+2)(k ~k+1) (k~k+2)$ hence we have all transpositions. Since every element in $S_{5}$ can be written as a product of transpositions we have that a two cycle and a 5 cycle generate $S_{5}$.